# Setting (ARIA) role for HTML custom elements without explicit attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria, custom-element

I have a web app that displays and passes around user-editable semantic markup. For a variety of reasons, including security, the markup consists entirely of custom elements (plus the `i`, `b`, and `u` tags). For regular rendering, I simply have styles for all the tags and stick them straight in the DOM. This looks and works great.

Now I'm doing screen-reader testing, and things aren't great. I have a bunch of graphical symbols I want to add labels for. I've got divs that I want to make into landmarks. I've got custom input fields and buttons.

It would be easy enough to just add `role=` to all the different tag instances. But part of the reason for the custom markup is to eliminate all the redundant information from the strings that get passed around (note: they're also compressed). My `<ns-math>` tag should always have `role="math"`, and adding 11 bytes to what might be tags around a single character is an actual problem when multiplied out over a whole article. I know this because the app started with a bunch of `<span class="...` type elements instead of custom.

For the fields and buttons, I've used a shadow DOM approach. This was necessary anyway to get focus/keyboard semantics correct without polluting the semantic markup with a bunch of redundant attributes, so it's easy to also slap the ARIA stuff on the shadow elements. Especially since the inputs are all leaf nodes. But most of my custom tags amount to fancy `span`s, and are mostly *not* leaf nodes, so I don't really want to shadow them *all* when they're working so well in the light DOM.

After a bunch of searching, it seems like the `internals.role` property from ["4.13.7.4 Accessibility semantics" of the HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#elementinternals) is maybe what I want. I may well be using it incorrectly (I'm a novice at front-end), but I can't seem to get this to work in recent versions of Firefox or Chrome. I don't get an error, but it seems to have no effect on the accessibility tree. My elements are not form-associated, but my reading is that the `ARIAMixin` should be functional anyway. This is maybe a working draft? If this is supposed to work in current browsers, does anybody have a code snippet or example?

Is there some other straight-forward way to achieve my goal of accessibility-annotating my custom elements without adding a bunch of explicit attributes to the element instances?

Answer (score 1):

So you want the benefit of adding a `role` or an `aria-attribute` without actually adding those attributes?  The concept of an "[accessibility object model](https://wicg.github.io/aom/spec/)" (AOM) has been bantering around a bit that would let you access and modify the accessibility tree directly but it's still in the works.  [Here's an article](https://hiddedevries.nl/en/blog/2019-07-22-meaning-without-markup-accessibility-object-model) from a couple years ago that talks about it.  Nothing official.  Just one person's thoughts.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds pretty much like what I want. I would expect that custom elements would have support for defining a default role.

Answer (score 1):

Further research shows that, as of this time, the abstracted accessibility options I'm asking for are not yet implemented.

For the time being: eliminating a number of page-owned enclosing `div`s from the accessibility hierarchy via `role="presentation"` significantly improved my overall tree. With those out of the way, the majority of my custom tags seem to be simply semantically ignored. This is *mostly* fine as the majority of my content is plain text.

Since I already mark up the vast majority of even single-character symbols, I've simply added *all* my symbols to the markup generator. Since everything is already in custom tags, I then use a shadow DOM `span` with `role="img"` and a character-specific `aria-label` to present the symbolic character.

My solution is still incomplete. I wish that I could convey the full richness of the semantic content I have available.